# OpenGL C++ Argument of type void is incompatible with parameter of type void(*)()

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, 3d

I am trying to draw several triangles in 3d and can't execute `glutDisplayFunc()` function. Here is my code:

Array of triangles and size.

```
int const trsize = (size-1)*(size-1)*2;
Triangle *trarr = new Triangle[trsize];
```

Code, where I try to call the function.

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(400,400);        
glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);    
glutCreateWindow("Height Map");     
Initialize();                       
glutDisplayFunc(Draw1(trarr, trsize));              
glutMainLoop();
```

`Draw1()` function.

```
void Draw1(Triangle arr[], int size){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i){
        glVertex3d((GLdouble)arr[i].p1().x(), (GLdouble)arr[i].p1().y(), (GLdouble)arr[i].p1().z());
        glVertex3d((GLdouble)arr[i].p2().x(), (GLdouble)arr[i].p2().y(), (GLdouble)arr[i].p2().z());
        glVertex3d((GLdouble)arr[i].p3().x(), (GLdouble)arr[i].p3().y(), (GLdouble)arr[i].p3().z());
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

I use VS2012 and IntelliSense writes: `argument of type "void" is incompatible with parameter of type "void (*)()"`

I don't know why `DisplayFunc` needs another type. With `Draw()` function without arguments it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[glutDisplayFunc](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node46.html) only allow function with that signature: void func(void).

so in you code, your drawing routine should be:

> void Draw1(void){...}

and you should find another way (global variable for example) to pass parameters to it. And your glut statement would be:

> glutDisplayFunc(Draw1);

Answer (score 0):

those parameters should be globals that you assign to as you set the drawFunc:

```
Triangle arr[];
int size;

void Draw1(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    for(int i=0; i<size; ++i){
        glVertex3d((GLdouble)arr[i].p1().x(), (GLdouble)arr[i].p1().y(), (GLdouble)arr[i].p1().z());
        glVertex3d((GLdouble)arr[i].p2().x(), (GLdouble)arr[i].p2().y(), (GLdouble)arr[i].p2().z());
        glVertex3d((GLdouble)arr[i].p3().x(), (GLdouble)arr[i].p3().y(), (GLdouble)arr[i].p3().z());
    }
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}


Initialize();         
arr = trarr; size = trsize;              
glutDisplayFunc(Draw1);              
glutMainLoop();
```

it's a shortcoming of the glut library that you have to use globals to pass data around the callbacks

Comment: @ratchetfreak you might want to correct that `glutDisplayFunc(Draw1()); ` to `glutDisplayFunc(Draw1);` or `glutDisplayFunc(&Draw1); ` so as not to confuse future reader